# Is there any way to disable a module and the modules which depend on it?

Tags: drush

Is there any way to disable a module and the modules which depend on it with Drush?

Let's say I need to disable the Views module, but I enabled the *Views Accordion* module as well. If I run `drush pm-disable views`, it does not disable the Views module.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You should update your Drush by the sounds of things. Doing `drush dis views` should result in the following:

> The following extensions will be disabled: views, views_bulk_operations, og_ui, views_content, og_example, views_php, views_ui
> Do you really want to continue? (y/n)

Which means the dependents are disabled at the same time.

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for pm-uninstall. instead, you will need to take the list of modules, pass it to pm-uninstall and repeat that command until all modules are uninstalled.

Comment: Yep, I often find myself just going to the actual uninstall page for uninstalling.

Comment: You are right, maybe I did a typo on the method.

Answer (score 1):

In Drupal 8, we can uninstall a module with `drush pm:uninstall oauth2`, for example.

Comment: Note that this not just disables the module. It will uninstall it, and remove all settings and corresponding tables in the database. In drupal 8 you can not disable modules anymore. See the answer here: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/268976/how-do-i-disable-a-module