# How do I disable a module?

Tags: 8, console

I am trying to disable modules in Drupal 8, and I found some solution like [Drupal console](https://drupalconsole.com/), but I am not sure how to use it with XAMPP.

I am unable to understand how I can disable a Drupal 8 module. With Drupal 7, that was possible directly from the user interface, but in Drupal 8 the checkboxes shown before the module name are disabled.

> [image]

How do I disable a module in Drupal 8?

Answer (score 7):

In Drupal 8, you cannot anymore disable modules: You can just install or uninstall them. Uninstalling a module has the same effect it had on Drupal 7 and previous versions: It removes the database tables the module installed.

On /admin/modules, Drupal shows you which modules are not installed, and which modules are installed. You can click the checkbox shown for the modules that aren't installed; clicking on *Install* at the bottom of the page will install them.

> [image: screenshot]

For installed modules, clicking on the checkbox shown before the module name doesn't have any effect. In fact, the checkbox is disabled.

To uninstall a module from the user interface, you just go to /admin/modules/uninstall (or click on the *Uninstall* tab visible on /admin/modules).

> [image: screenshot]

> [image: screenshot]

Select the modules you want to uninstall, and click on the *Uninstall* button shown on the bottom of the page.

Keep in mind that Drupal can still not being able to uninstall a module for various reasons, for example because the module implements an entity and you created those entities on the site.

You could also use Drupal Console for uninstalling a module, but you would need to install it (on the server). After you install it, and open a terminal window on the Drupal root directory of the site, with `drupal module:uninstall <module_name>` you would uninstall the `<module_name>` module.

From the user interface it's easier. It's the only possible way, if you are working on a remote site for which the provider doesn't allow you to use an SSH shell.

Answer (score 2):

We can't disable modules in D8 so you can just uninstall them :

I recommend to use drush :

```
drush pm-uninstall [your_module_name]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to type the command and you need change `sites/defulft/settings.php` `$databases` conect  host `localhost` to `127.0.0.1`

**Disable module**

```
./vendor/bin/drupal mou module_name
```

**Enable module**

```
./vendor/bin/drupal moi module_name
```

**List all**

```
./vendor/bin/drupal list
```

Comment: in Drupal 8, you don't disable modules: You just install or uninstall them, but that is different from disabling them, since disabling them would not remove the configuration nor the database tables used from the module.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, Without disable How I can Uninstall them ? and according to your comment where Can I run those commands to do same ?